# MVC Tables from model list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of objects from my database that i want to show over my webpage in table like this:

[image]

My object have several properties which i want to be inside columns name (fileName, Size, Protocol).

this is my view:

```
@model List<Application.Models.Objects>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowList";
}
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.fileName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Thats what i have for now.

Comment: Of course, hot can i do that ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're wanting to know how to accomplish the extended features of the table above, including:

- Paging
- Icons
- Sorting

You have basically three options:  Roll Your Own (implement these features yourself,) use OSS, or Buy.

There are a number of free options based on jQuery and other client-side UI frameworks.  Google "jQuery Grid" for those.  There are also many for sale from vendors, specifically targeted to ASP.NET MVC.  Google can also help you there.

Comment: I saw this one: http://flexigrid.info/ how hard is to implement this ? (i am a new developer)

Comment: No harder than any other coding tasks. There may be a learning curve if you're not accustomed to jQuery/Javascript but it looks like that grid has some good examples you can follow.

Comment: Can i have a guide ? i don't even know what to do with all those files